# Selenium - Click at certain position : How do you know the exact position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here's my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.mergermarket.com/homepage'
driver.get(url)

deals = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div/div[2]/nav/ul/li[4]/a')
urldeals = deals.get_attribute("href")
driver.get(urldeals)

custom1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchCriteriaSummary"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div')
custom1.click()
time.sleep(2)

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(custom1, 30, -5)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

Here's what I want : On the website I have this dropdown

[image: dropdown]

I would like my script to click on the arrow, that's what I did with this line of code :

```
custom1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchCriteriaSummary"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div')
custom1.click()
```

Then after this line of code, the dropdown look like this :

[image: dropdown2]

And I tried to tell Selenium to click on `Custom` with `ActionChain` with

```
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(custom1, 30, -5)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

But it doesn't work, the code worked, but it didn't click on `Custom`. Maybe I didn't use `move_to_element_with_offset` correclty but How should I know the right pixel to move my cursor ?

I tried to use `Select` instead of `ActionChains` before but it seems there is no Select in the html code so it didn't work either, I got an error : `selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>`

EDIT :

I found a way to freeze the brower's inspector, here the code of the dropdown

[image: dropdown]

Comment: Any demo creds to login?

Comment: I cannot transmit them :/

Comment: You should find the element and use click method on it.  (Hopefully it's not too finicky about staying open when you check the browser's inspector, but there are ways to sort of freeze that.)  If you must use actionschain, it'll be a bit of trial and error. (and location would change based on platform/resolution) You can get the position of a webelement, but you need to locate it first.  (and at that point might as well use the click.)

Comment: That's my question, how to locate it first ?

Comment: And yes it's finicky, it close when I check the browser's inspector..

Comment: I would need some sort of freeze, lik you said.

Comment: I found how to do that, I edited my post

Comment: Where this page occurs after login? I tried to create temp login but could not see the page where this dropdown appears? will be great if you can share the page URL ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot :/ I found a solution, I will update my post later